# How do you construct a MouseEvent?

Tags: java, mouseevent

I know this question is very simple, but I cannot figure out how to construct it. It seems to have a lot of parameters, and I not only don't know what to put in them, but I also don't even know what a component is.  It would be great if someone could explain using basic concepts. Thanks

Comment: There are a numerous ways of doing this. If you want to make use of Javas innate ability then I suggest this https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/mouselistener.html

Answer (score 0):

There are 3 steps you need:
1. You have to implement the Mouselistener interface in your GUI class
2. Add the listener to a GUI element which it should listen to
3. Implement the event listener for your specific mouse event (will also be required by the compiler after you add the interface to your class)
For help: tutorial from Oracle https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/mouselistener.html

Answer (score 0):

MouseEvent can not be effectively used without MouseListener.

To use MouseListener, you have to either use:

```
public class StackTest implements MouseListener{
public static void main(String[] args){

}
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent arg0){
}
public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent arg0){
}
public void mouseExited(MouseEvent arg0){
}
public void mousePressed(MouseEvent arg0){
}
public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent arg0){
}
```

Or, you would use

```
    component.addMouseListener(new MouseListener(){
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent arg0){
        }
        public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent arg0){
        }
        public void mouseExited(MouseEvent arg0){
        }
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent arg0){
        }
        public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent arg0){
        }
    });
```

Either works, just as long as the component is able to have a MouseListener implemented into it. Those five methods are required too, and they all have their own invokes.

- mouseClicked

  This is invoked when the user presses any button on the mouse within the component.
- mouseEntered

  This is invoked when a user's mouse enters the component's region.
- mouseExited

  This is invoked when a user's mouse leaves the component's region.
- mousePressed

  This is invoked when a user presses their Left Mouse Button on the component.
- mouseReleased

  This is invoked when a user releases any of the buttons on the mouse after it has been pressed over the component

**NOTE:**  mouseClicked will **ALWAYS** be invoked before mouseReleased, and the same goes with mouseEntered and mouseExited, respectively.

These methods will also be invoked regardless of whether or not there is any code in them.

Now, a `component` is an object that descends from the `Component` class. Components are things such a JButtons, JPanels, JFrames, etc. and all the modern components you see are from from the `javax.swing` package. For example, you may have seen the `JOptionPane`.

The `JOptionPane` is just a JFrame, a JLabel, and a JButton.

All of those are components that can have an `Event Listener`. An `event listener` does exactly what it says. It listens for specific events. `MouseListener` for example, listens for events involving the user's Mouse.

You can learn more about components [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/)